# Get number of rows retrieved in crystal report while generating from Java

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I have a crystal report  - which can be generated from JAVA - using CrystalReportsRuntime api and other supporting apis. How can I find the number of rows retrieved for the query configured in the report template in runtime.

One way is extracting the query from the report and can be executed manually. But the problem is Sequence is used in the report query and when it is executed twice(one to check the result count and another to generate the report), the sequence value increments two times.

Comment: one way is place any field in detail section and then take count of that field which will give you the number of records retrived

Comment: How do you plan to use this row count?  Is it needed within the scope of the crystal report, or is the need outside the scope of the crystal report and withing the scope of your Java application?

Also, how is the sequence built into the query?  Was this done with a database stored procedure that the crystal report is using to retrieve it's datasource?

Comment: Simple sql query configured in report file (say select myseq.nextval from dual). 
I need within the java app.
The scope is to check the row count of the result of the sql query, while generating the report.
I want to show user a error message when there is no result in the query.
But I don't want to explicitly extract the query from the report and execute it.

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to do this using Crystal Report.  It shouldn't be difficult in Java though, but you are going to need to create another simple query that selects the same data the report would select, but without the sequence.  I believe you will also want to use this same non-sequenced query to test the dataset for error handling purposes before the crystal report is ever called by the application.  Give that a shot in your Java application, then if you still need help you can start a new question in the Java tag.